# I don't know how to use real path in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to use this code but it gives me an error :

```
   // root path    defined("ROOT_PATH") 
   || define("ROOT_PATH", realpath(dirname(__ FILE__) . DS."..".DS));
```

this is the error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'FILE__' (T_STRING) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/op/inc/config.php on line 20

Comment: There shouldn't be a space between __ and FILE__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra space in `__ FILE__` , It should be `__FILE__`.

Not sure if you did that just for formatting here.